# Put Assetic back in dynamic mode after assetic dump

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I'm using Symfony2 and Assetic. Lately I've been doing a lot of CSS work so at a certain point I needed the command

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Ever since I've used it I need to run that command everytime I change CSS to see the difference. Now I've did some research and found out that I can put Assetic in to watch mode so I don't have to run the command above after every change using the following command:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --watch --env=prod
```

However, I just want it back to before I put it into this manual mode. The Symfony2 documentation explains how to do an assetic dump, but not how to put it back in dynamic mode (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files)

Does anyone know how to put it back in dynamic mode?

Comment: Do you have `assetic: `
              `debug:          %kernel.debug%`
    `use_controller: true` in your config.yml?

Comment: Yes, my assetic part in config.yml: http://pastebin.com/495BTwsm

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely possibilities for Symfony not dynamically serving assets from the internal controller:

#### 1. assetic.use_controller is not really true

Confirm 100% you are telling Symfony `assetic.use_controller` is `true`. One straightforward method of debugging would be adding this to the top of your controller action and reloading the page:

```
var_dump($this->container->getParameter('assetic.use_controller'));die();
```

Not getting `true` as a return value could mean you are overriding `use_controller` in either `config_dev.php` or `config_prod.php` depending on what environment you are pointing at.

#### 2. Your web server is checking for static assets before passing to Symfony

Most webservers can be configured to check if a URL points to a physical file asset and deliver that file. So if you have dumped assets in Symfony, the webserver might be serving that file and not passing the request onto Symfony.

- For nginx see: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files
- For apache see: [Apache rewrite rule similar to Nginx try_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104610/apache-rewrite-rule-similar-to-nginx-try-files)

The solution would be to remove the dumped asset files from the file system. Their location depends on where you configured them to go, but check in `web/js`, `web/bundles`, etc.